# SQL Server 2005 Query XML Data Type related

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005

I am selecting 2 sets of columns from the same table, as follows.

```
select (select a, b, c from T1 FOR XML RAW('CAT1')),
       (select d, e, f from T1 FOR XML RAW('CAT2'))
for XML PATH('Parent')
```

The result of the query is

```
<Parent>&lt;CAT1 a="Data1" b="Data2', c="Data3" &gt;&lt;CAT2 d="Data4" e="Data5" f="Data6"&gt;</Parent>
```

How to avoid? I would get enclosed in a proper parent xml?

Expected Result

```
<Parent>
   <CAT1 a="Data1" b="Data2', c="Data3">
   <CAT2 d="Data4" e="Data5" f="Data6">
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TYPE` to specify that the sub queries should return XML.

```
select (select a, b, c from T1 FOR XML RAW('CAT1'), TYPE),
       (select d, e, f from T1 FOR XML RAW('CAT2'), TYPE)
for XML PATH('Parent')
```

[TYPE Directive in FOR XML Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190025%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)